# Ubuntu 18.04 Netplan routing to VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge, netplan

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server with Hetzner on which Virtualbox 
is running Windows server '12.

The host has ip: `144.76.116.79`
I've got an additional ip, `144.76.116.125`, since I want all traffic incoming and outgoing to `144.76.116.125` directly routed to the VM. However I'm struggling for the 3rd day now, locking me out of my server on a regular base and also scratching my head because I just can't get it to work.

My current configuration looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 144.76.116.79/32
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 144.76.116.61
      gateway6: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.133.100.100
          - 213.133.98.98
          - 213.133.99.99
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9999
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9898
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:1010
  bridges:
    vmbr0:
      macaddress: 00:50:56:00:E5:94
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ enp2s0 ]
      addresses: [ 144.76.116.125/27 ]
```

I can't access the VM through it's public ip.

Comment: did you solved this? I am struggling also since two days and I am looking for a solution..

Comment: I eventually gave up and worked around it by using virtualbox via its gui. I added a 2nd network adapter where I only thrown in the mac adress for the 2nd IP I got.